# my images cant loaded in image view after clicking the images

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-fileprovider

i have two image view and two button, when clicking on source button it will take image and fit in sourceImageView and second is also doing same work in targetImageView and the i do image uploadin to s3 bucket and face comrasion ,
this entire code work in proper way in some mobile but not in every mobile like motorola e5 plus (in this code will not fit image to targetImageView when i click image from camera ) i cant figure out what is the problem ,in my phone its working

File Provider for both images

```
 choosePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            uri =FileProvider.getUriForFile ( mContext,"com.example.testing.MainActivity.fileProvider",mSourcePhotoFile );
            captureImage.putExtra ( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri );
            List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities = getPackageManager ().queryIntentActivities ( captureImage,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );
            for (ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
                Log.d ( "forEachLoop",activity.toString () );
                grantUriPermission ( activity.activityInfo.packageName,uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
            }

            startActivityForResult ( captureImage,CAMERA_REQUEST2 );
        }
    } );

takePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            uri =FileProvider.getUriForFile ( mContext,"com.example.testing.MainActivity.fileProvider",mPhotoFile );
            captureImage.putExtra ( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri );
            List<ResolveInfo> cameraActivities = getPackageManager ().queryIntentActivities ( captureImage,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );
            for (ResolveInfo activity : cameraActivities){
                Log.d ( "forEachLoop",activity.toString () );
                grantUriPermission ( activity.activityInfo.packageName,uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
            }

            startActivityForResult ( captureImage,CAMERA_REQUEST );
        }
    } );


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
       Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile ( this,"com.example.testing.MainActivity.fileProvider",mPhotoFile );
       targetImagePathInput = uri.toString ();
       revokeUriPermission ( uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
        try {
            updatePhotoView ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile ( this,"com.example.testing.MainActivity.fileProvider",mSourcePhotoFile );
        sourceImagePathInput = uri.toString ();
        revokeUriPermission ( uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
        try {
            updatePhotoViewSource ();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Do you see any errors or crashes in the logcat on those devices?

Comment: @DavidWasser in all the phone this code is working fine but when it comes to moto this problem arises, no crashes or error in other fone but in moto i never tested with android studio,but when someone uses this code in moto ,this problem happen....

Comment: @DavidWasser N thank u sir  for response....